# Javascript | add json object to empty json array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a empty json array.

```
shoppingCart: []
```

I have a json object.

```
let product = {"name": "name", "price": "price", "quantity": "quantity", "logoPath": "logoPath"};
```

I am trying to add json object to json array.

```
let obj = JSON.parse(state.shoppingCart);
obj.push(product);
state.shoppingCart = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

I got this error:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"
```

I wanna add many object to empy array like that:

```
shoppingCart: [{id: 1, name: name1}, {id: 2, name: name2}, {id: 3, name: name3}]
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What does the literal state of `shoppingCart` and `product` look like at the time of `.push()`?

Comment: @symlink Both of them same as above.

Comment: for your information, first code is not a json array, this is an empty javascript object litteral. JSON is a data format, "coded" as a string ; same thing with the second code

Comment: @Pierre thanks for information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the line where you try to `JSON.parse()` `shoppingCart`

```js
let shoppingCart = []

let product = {
  "name": "name", 
  "price": "price", 
  "quantity": "quantity", 
  "logoPath": "logoPath"
}

//let obj = JSON.parse(shoppingCart)
shoppingCart.push(product)
shoppingCart = JSON.stringify(shoppingCart)

console.log(shoppingCart)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question clearly...but if you want arr of json is go something like this:

```
let arr = []
let myObj1 = {"name": "name1", "price": 1, "quantity": 1, "logoPath": "logoPath1"};
let myObj2 = {"name": "name"2, "price": 2, "quantity": 2, "logoPath": "logoPath2"};
arr.push(myObj1)
arr.push(myObj2)
console.log(arr)
```

hope that is helpful